# UPDATE COM CASE NÃO FUNCIONA

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, syntax-error, cast

Estou trabalhando com um bando de dados (Postgres) sobre vestibular e estava querendo fazer um update juntando duas tabelas e com o uso do UPDATE CASE WHEN THEN. Estava relacionando as duas tabelas por meio dos ids delas e utilizava um campo de cada para criar a condição de update da tabela com valores novos.
OBS: Esses valores que estariam sendo adicionados não existem nas tabelas e eu não queria perder tempo em fazer vários updates separados ou inserts separados.

Segue o código:

```
-- UPDATE PARA ADIÇÃO DO ID SISTEMA VAGA FINAL PARA CANDIDATOS INDEFERIDOS NO TESTE DE APTIDÃO E PCD (MUSICA)
UPDATE sigconcursos.inscricao AS insc 
SET id_vaga_final = id_vaga_segunda_opcao,
id_vaga_sistema_vagas_final CASE
WHEN id_vaga_segunda_opcao = 262 THEN id_vaga_sistema_vagas_final = 812 -- ID VAGA SEGUNDA OPÇÃO DETERMINA QUAL VAGA SEGUIR PCD
WHEN id_vaga_segunda_opcao = 270 THEN id_vaga_sistema_vagas_final = 835
WHEN id_vaga_segunda_opcao = 286 THEN id_vaga_sistema_vagas_final = 881
FROM sigconcursos.analise_inscricao AS aninsc
WHERE insc.id_inscricao = aninsc.id_inscricao AND insc.id_vaga = 284
AND insc.id_vaga_sistema_vagas = 875 AND aninsc.id_status = 3 AND insc.id_concurso = 16
```

O Erro:

```
O campo id_vaga_sistema_vagas_final é um inteiro e a operação retorna um booleano.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não está utilizando o `CASE` de forma sintaticamente correta.
Note que no caso de `(id_vaga_segunda_opcao = 262)` você está retornando o resultado da expressão `id_vaga_sistema_vagas_final = 812`, que será verdadeiro ou falso, e não atribuindo `812` à `id_vaga_sistema_vagas_final`.
A sintaxe correta é:

```
CASE expression
    WHEN value THEN result
    [WHEN ...]
    [ELSE result]
END
```

Dessa forma seu comando deveria ser:

```
UPDATE sigconcursos.inscricao AS insc 
SET id_vaga_final = id_vaga_segunda_opcao,
        id_vaga_sistema_vagas_final =   
            CASE    WHEN id_vaga_segunda_opcao = 262 THEN 812 -- ID VAGA SEGUNDA OPÇÃO DETERMINA QUAL VAGA SEGUIR PCD
                    WHEN id_vaga_segunda_opcao = 270 THEN 835
                    WHEN id_vaga_segunda_opcao = 286 THEN 881
                    ELSE 0
            END
FROM sigconcursos.analise_inscricao AS aninsc
WHERE insc.id_inscricao = aninsc.id_inscricao
  AND insc.id_vaga = 284
  AND insc.id_vaga_sistema_vagas = 875
  AND aninsc.id_status = 3
  AND insc.id_concurso = 16
```

Comment: Nossa mano, realmente eu estava fazendo de forma muito errada kkkk. Realmente por isso sempre estava retornando erro de compatibilidade. Como estava trabalhando com várias tasks, acabei deixando passar esse detalhe. Valeu pela dica :)